# How to insert records in a existing table using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

```
 Declare Userrole_Cursor Cursor For
 Select (User_Role_id,
     Pos_entity_Id,
     User_role_code,
     User_Role_description,
     Print_Sequence,
     Update_date,
     Tx_id,
     Add_date,
     Add_Username,
     Update_Username,
     Active_Flag) from User_Role_Tb where pos_entity_id = (pos_entity_id)

     Open Cursor 

  FETCH NEXT FROM UserRole_Cursor into
```

the above is the Cursor creation i have written, now need to insert in all the mentioned columns in a User_role_tb. please help. this is the first time i am using cursor.

Comment: Google some "sample on using cursor in sql server"

Comment: I tried but could not find anything understanding or simple  that actually inserts into a table.

Comment: Why even bother with a **cursor**? Those are evil, waste your CPU cycles - just avoid them whenever you can ! (and most of the time, **you can!**)

Answer (score 2):

This simple example can help you

```
-- assume this is your table
create table #tmp (MyDbName varchar(100), MyDbId int, MyStatus int)

-- you need to have a variable for each field. 
DECLARE @MyDbName varchar(100)
DECLARE @MyDbId int
DECLARE @MyDbStatus int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT name, [dbid], [status]
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @MyDbName, @MyDbId, @MyDbStatus    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    -- insert data into your table using variables
    insert into #tmp (MyDbName, MyDbId, MyStatus)
    values (@MyDbName, @MyDbId, @MyDbStatus)

    -- fetch next row from cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @MyDbName, @MyDbId, @MyDbStatus    
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

-- select from your table to make sure data is there
select * from #tmp
```

Comment: Thank you. but could you please let me know if i can hard code two columns and insert the data as it is the other columns?

Comment: Is it mandotory i should create variables from all my columns i am going to  insert?

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: No i need to insert all the columns so i should create variables for all of them right. ok will do it. os will it be something like this in my case                          
          insert into User_role_tb ( col1 ,col2 .....col9) then values would be the variables i declare? please correct me if im wrong

Comment: I am afraid this a long and vague process , i am creating all the variables for the columns present and inserting them one by one. is this the only way possible?

Comment: What ever you need to insert into your table, should be hard coded or variables you can get using  cursor or any individual query. You also can use join when defining cursor. There is no other way.